# How to get the context inside a nested class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Because `show` is needed only inside the nested class `ButtonHandler`, I want to do the following

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private class ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
           // removed for simplicity
        }
        private void show(String s)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, s, LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }   

}
```

instead of the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private class ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
           // removed for simplicity
        }
    }

    private void show(String s)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, s, LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

## Question

How to get the context `this` for `Toast.makeText` in the first approach? I am familiar with c# but not java and android.

Comment: Since your inner class is not stati has access to the outer environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `ButtonHandler` is a non-static inner class (which it appears to be), you can just use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` in order to have a reference to a `Context`:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If `ButtonHandler` is static (so `MainActivity.this` doesn't work), you'll have to pass a context object to the method somehow. Assuming you're calling `show()` from the `onClick()` method, you can leverage `View.getContext()` and write this:

```
show(v.getContext(), s);
```

```
private void show(Context c, String s)
{
    Toast.makeText(c, s, LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: The concept of nested class in java is different from c#. In c#, accessing `OuterClass.this` from within `InnerClass` is not allowed by design.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify *which* class when dealing with nested classes.

Using `this` refers to `ButtonHandler`, which isn't going to work since it doesn't have the context itself. Instead, use `MainActivity.this` (`this@MainActivity` in Kotlin) to refer to the outer class:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Outer classes instances can be accessed via `MainActivity.this`. As well, fields can be access via `MainActivity.this.field`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a private variable

```
private Activity activity;
```

and in your onCreate method:

```
this.activity = this;
```

because in every nested class you have access to every outer variable, but just "this" does ofcourse not work. So your example would be sth like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Activity activity;

    public void onCreate(...){
        this.activity = this;
        ...
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
           // removed for simplicity
        }
        private void show(String s)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(activity, s, LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }   

}
```

please don't kill me for no good code style